# ANR from a coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

As a longtime Java programmer migrating to Kotlin, I've been working to wrap my head around coroutines. Generally, I think I have a pretty good grasp of them now, but then I come across a case like this...

I have what I feel is a classic use for coroutines: do a long-running operation without blocking the UI thread. I've structured my code like this:

```
fun updateUI() {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        doUpdate()
        // update the UI with results of doUpdate()
    }
}
```

and

```
suspend fun doUpdate() =
    withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        // long-running operations here
    }
```

...where `updateUI` is called on the main (UI) thread.

Running it interactively in my dev environment, it seems to work as expected - the UI thread isn't blocked, and no ANR is reported.

However, my Play console is reporting ANRs for this code:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
| group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x75eb4268 self=0xa8784e00
| sysTid=4957 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xab948534
| state=R schedstat=( 178941824 76636302 233 ) utm=6 stm=11 core=1 HZ=100
| stack=0xbe61c000-0xbe61e000 stackSize=8MB
| held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
at com.mypackage.ClassName.doUpdate (ClassName.java:66)
- locked <0x04706efb> (a com.mypackage.ClassName)
at com.mypackage.ClassName$updateUI$1.invokeSuspend (ClassName.java:149)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith (BaseContinuationImpl.java:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run (DispatchedTask.java:241)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6823)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1563)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

Could anyone with more coroutine experience offer any insight on this?

Comment: do you cancel your long running operation when your activity gets destroyed?

Comment: @Pawel is that relevant to my ANR? Anyway, this isn't in an activity, it's called from a BroadcastReceiver, which doesn't get notification of being destroyed.